# Gaussian measure on Banach spaces

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, gaussian

Given any separable Banach space $B$ and a centered Gaussian measure $Q$ on it with Cameron-Martin space $H$, does there exist a Hilbert space $G$ and a Gaussian measure $W$ on it such that following hold

1) $B$ is a dense subspace of $G$ and restriction of $W$ to $B$ is $Q$ (that makes $W$ supported on $B$).

2) $(B,Q)$ and $(G,W)$ have the same Cameron-Martin space $H$.

Comment: It seems to me that your question is simply "can any separable Banach space be densely embedded into some Hilbert space". The answer to this is obviously yes.

Comment: @Martin: How does one prove that? I was thinking in the same direction.

Comment: Take a sequence $\ell_n$ of linear functionals of norm $1$ on $B$ such that $\|x\|_B = \sup_{n} \ell_n(x)$. (This exists by separability.) Then complete $B$ under the norm $\|x\|_H^2 = \sum_n n^{-2} |\ell_n(x)|^2$.

Comment: B may still have measure 0 in G wrt W measure in this construction.

Comment: @Nate Supposing the assertion were true, wont it reduce the study of Gaussian measures on Banach spaces to that on Hilbert spaces?

Comment: @user44179: I think the idea is to define $W$ as the extension of $Q$ to $G$ (so that $W(G \setminus B) = 0$).  In other words, $W$ is the pushforward of $Q$ under the inclusion map.  For your second comment, note that many of the interesting aspects of $Q$ have to do with its interaction with the topology of $B$; the interaction of $W$ with the topology of $H$ may not be as interesting.  For example, if $Q$ is Wiener measure, asking about the uniform norm and the $L^2$ norm of a Brownian motion gives us very different information.